# What is a good open source Windows finance software

Tags: software, sole-proprietorship, gnucash

I have played around with GnuCash a little but it doesn't quite meet up to what I am looking for. I currently run QuickBooks and use class tracking to keep a fine line of separation between my personal and business finances. I didn't see anything like this in GnuCash but maybe I missed something.

So, what does anyone suggest?

Comment: Calculator. ;) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried others on [Wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages#Finance) list?

Comment: I have looked at that. I was hoping someone could recommends something they have used and found to be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using class tracking to keep business and personal operations separate. I'm pretty sure the IRS and courts frown upon this, and you're probably risking losing any limited liability you may have.

And for keeping separate parts of the business separate, like say stores in a franchise, one approach would be subaccounts. Messy, I'm sure.